# Updating one element of a bound Observable collection

Tags: c#, listview, gridview, binding, observablecollection

I have an observable collection with a custom class called `songInfo` inside.
It is bound to a `ListView`. Here is the code for the binding:

**C#**:

```
var songData = new ObservableCollection<songInfo>();

public ObservableCollection<songInfo> _songData
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return songData; 
    } 
}

public class songInfo
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Album { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Ext { get; set; }
    public bool isSongPlaying { get; set; }
}
```

**XAML**:

```xml
<Window x:Class="Genesis.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Genesis (Alpha)" Height="897" Width="882" Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Name="Genesis">

    <ListView Margin="12,39,0,0" Name="Library" DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding _songData}" Height="681" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseDoubleClick="Library_MouseDoubleClick"  ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContextMenu}" AlternationCount="2" Background="AliceBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="846">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="gvLibrary">
                <GridViewColumn Width="20" Header="hi" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding isSongPlaying}" x:Name="gvColumnPlaying" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="220" Header="Title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" x:Name="gvColumnTitle" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="180" Header="Artist" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Artist}" x:Name="gvColumnArtist" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="180" Header="Album" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Album}" x:Name="gvColumnAlbum" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="180" Header="Location" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Location}" x:Name="gvColumnLocation" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="80" Header="File Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Ext}" x:Name="gvColumnFileType" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

The songInfo is populated at other points in my code. When elements are added or removed, the ListView is updated. However, there are points when I simply change just `songInfo.Ext` or `songInfo.Location`, etc. I found a convoluted way to do this and update, but I had to remove the element and re-add it:

```
songInfo temp = songData[playing_song_index];
songData.RemoveAt(playing_song_index);
songData.Insert(playing_song_index, new songInfo()
{
    Title = temp.Title,
    Artist = temp.Artist,
    Album = temp.Album,
    Location = temp.Location,
    Ext = temp.Ext,
    isSongPlaying = true
});
```

That changes isSongPlaying to true.

**Is there an easier way to just update one "column" of the GridView?**

Answer (score 6):

Your `songInfo` class needs to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

If you implement this interface properly, then changes to members of the class will automatically get reflected within the user interface via the binding.

Answer (score 3):

If songInfo doesn't use INotifyPropertyChanged, then what you are doing will work. You could clean it up a bit by:

```
var mySong = songData.//get your song
int index = songData.IndexOf( mySong );
songData.Remove( mySong  );
songData.Insert( index, mySong );
```

Comment: I do have to change a property of the song.

Comment: Then update the property and re-insert. There's no need to re-create the object. However, using `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your `songData` class would be the better route.

Comment: This idea worked for me although i had INotifyPropertyChanged with my property.